# Select a substring before the second occurrence of a character without a string slice

Tags: python, substring

How can I select a substring, using python, that only contains the characters up to the second colon? For example, let's say I have a string ABC*01:02:03:04, and another, A*101:23:444. How could I extract the substrings A*01:02 and ABC*101:23 from the above strings, without using a string splicer, that is, something along the lines of mystring[:5]?

Comment: Why is string splice out of bounds?

Comment: I want to define a generic method which extracts the specified subsequence. I will do a quick edit to make this more understandable.

Comment: What do you mean by string splicer?  "".split() or the indexer on the string?

Comment: I don't see you being able to pull out a substring without using the `mystr[:someIndex]` syntax. So please, PLEASE update your question to indicate exactly what functionalities are out of bounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could write

```
':'.join('ABC*01:02:03:04'.split(':')[:2])
```

It uses splicing, but it gives you the first two groups instead of an fixed amount of characters

Comment: Why not `':'.join('ABC*01:02:03:04'.split(':',2)[:-1])` for less splitting?

Comment: I don't see the big difference, imo its just preference

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions.

```
import re
re.match(r'(.*?:.*?):.*', 'ABC*01:02:03:04').groups()[0]
-> 'ABC*01:02'
re.match(r'(.*?:.*?):.*', 'A*01:02:03:0').groups()[0]
-> 'A*01:02'
```

Comment: I had just come up with `re.match('.*?:.*?(?=:)','ABC*01:02:03:04').group(0)` -- I like the lookahead, I think it's slightly cleaner, but as far as I see it, it's a Tomato, tomato issue.

Comment: @mgilson yeah, I wouldn't argue. Also, your `group(0)` is slightly better than my `groups()[0]` in this case.

Comment: How would you compile the regex, then use the .groups()[0] command. For example, let's say that my_reg = re.compile(r'(.*?:.*?):.*'), and I want to call my_reg.match("some str:i:ng").groups[0]. But this does not work in my program

Comment: I think regex is overkill here. Still, +1 for a working solution